# What to do with an edit that adds very pertinent information to an answer?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I came across an edit in which the user is adding very pertinent information to an answer. More specifically, the answer looked like:

> To solve this, do something.

The user edited the answer with a distinction between version 1.x and 2.x like this:

> To solve this in version 1.x, do something.
>
> To solve this in version 2.x, do something else.

The distinction is very interesting, especially because no information about the version was specified in the question. It was not made by the author of the answer though. In theory, I believe that I should reject the edit because it is an attempt to answer and it is not exactly what the author intended to say. From what I understand, it would be better according to the guidelines to put this information in another answer.

Nevertheless, I fear that this valuable piece of the information will be lost if I simply reject the edit (the user may simply give up after one failed edit). Also, it seems to me that it is much more compact (and thus more accessible) to have all this information about the same technique in the same answer.

What should we do in this case?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is called updating a post and it's covered by the help center as something we want users to do:

> #### When should I edit posts?
>
> Any time you see a post that needs improvement and are inclined to
>   suggest an edit, you are welcome to do so. The original author of a
>   question or answer may always edit their own post, regardless of
>   reputation level.
>
> Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than
>   you found it. Common reasons for edits include:
>
> - To fix grammar and spelling mistakes
> - To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)
> - To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place
> - To correct minor mistakes or **add updates as the post ages**
> - To add related resources or hyperlinks

The post is ageing. Having up-to-date information at the top is desired. This would be an example of someone doing exactly this. [This has happened before](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6087453/4).

Answer (score 15):

It depends. I would ask yourself a couple of questions

## Does this keep with the intent of the original answer?

It's quite possible that version 2 does something very different from version 1, while achieving the same result. As long as they're aiming to do the same thing, but using *language enforced changes* it should be fine. If it's a purely semantic argument (poh-tay-toh vs poh-tah-toh), don't approve it. In other words, don't introduce noise into an already clear answer.

## Would another answer be found?

In most cases the answer is yes, but on an old canonical where there's 15 answers with a combined score of 500, the answer might be no. In that case, I would favor appending new information over posting a new answer that will be so far down the list it would never be seen.

Comment: As Shog says "intent doesn't matter". Meaning does.

Comment: In this case, both lines of code are doing the same thing and are in fact quite similar. Yet, the answer from the author was only working in v1.x and the suggested edit only works in v2.x. Therefore we can consider this as an update of the post (as suggested below). Also, I do believe that the intent/meaning is preserved. Thanks a lot for your answer which clarified things for me.

Answer (score -1):

### If the edit adds a substantially new solution, reject it.

If you accept such edit, the score of the answer becomes meaningless - you now have two separate answers, but only one score.

- The edited-in answer starts with a score that it didn't earn on its own merits
- If the new solution turns out to be wrong, should the community downvote the answer (impacting also the original solution), or should we leave an answer that's in part wrong with a (presumably) high score?

It would be better to add the new solution as a separate answer, and edit the original answer to indicate that it only works in version 1.x.

---

That said, there are cases where editing to add new solution for new version may be appropriate, as per Machavity's answer. The same goes for adding a solution for the 2.x version that is substantially the same as the original solution (i.e. it might use new syntax or libraries, but uses the same approach as the original solution).